# cannot instantiate the type with Java

Tags: java, instantiation

I have these two classes:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class Polygon {
public ArrayList<double[]> vertex = new ArrayList<double[]>();
int i;  

public Polygon() {
    double[] a= {0,0,0};
    vertex.add(a);
}

public ArrayList<double[]> getVertex() {
    for (i=0; i<vertex.size(); ++i) {
        vertex.get(i);
    }
    return vertex;
}
public void addVertex(double[] x) {
    if (x.length == 2) {
        vertex.add(x);
    }
}
```

and Polygon2:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Polygon2 {
private ArrayList<Polygon> x = new ArrayList<Polygon>();
public Polygon2() {
    x.add(new Polygon());
}
public Polygon2(int n) {
    for (int i=0; i< n; ++i) {
        x.add(new Polygon());
    }
}
public void addPolygon(Polygon y){
    x.add(y);
}
public void removePolygon(int y) {
    if (y<x.size()) {
        x.remove(y);
    }
}
```

under the default constructor of Polygon2, when I did x.add(new Polygon()); it underlines red on the Polygon and said cannot instantiate

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include the current source code you have and the full error message you get from the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialize an abstract class. Remove the `abstract` keyword from `Polygon` then this issue will gone. 
Also it should not be an abstract class since you haven't define any abstract method.

Comment: Hi, I deleted the abstract in abstract class and it still shows the same error

Answer (score 0):

Polygon is an abstract class, you cannot instantiate that. If you still have to use new Polygon() then go for anonymous object!
something like this: but I'd suggest you don't use this unless you know what you're doing

```
x.add(new Polygon(){});
```

Comment: Hi, I deleted the abstract in abstract class and it still shows the same error

Comment: @Elters another thing is that you missed the closing parenthesis at the end of both the classes